# Proper Location for Transparent Squid Proxy Gateway (with Caching)

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up a transparent proxy on my home network so that I can cache my internet traffic and monitor my connections without needing to configure browsers to go through the proxy - e.g. it should be transparent. AFAIK Squid can do this, according to its documentation, but what's not clear to me is where I need to put the machine in my physical network topology in order for it to work.

My home network connects to the internet via a cable modem, which has an ethernet connection to a router running OpenWRT. This router forms the switch which connects all my wireless and wired clients and home servers.

Does the transparent proxy gateway I want to set up simply connect as another client to the router's switch, or do I set it up on the path between the router and the modem somehow? If so, do I need to put it in a DMZ of some sort, or should it simply act as the router as well, and my present router can just get DHCP info from the squid gateway and act as a switch for the rest of my LAN?

If there are multiple options, which one would be best for maximum performance?

If it matters, here's my Squid Gateway rig's relevant spec:
Celeron J1800
4gb RAM
64gb SSD
3x gigabit ethernet (2x on broadcom discrete PCI-E card)
1x wireless a/b/g mpcie card
Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: The router has to divert the traffic, that much is certain. I'll try to provide a more complete answer later.

Comment: Do you need to intercept IPv6 traffic?

Comment: @DanielB, I assume I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine hosting the proxy can be set up side-by-side with your regular clients in your local network. The router would route all HTTP traffic (except from the proxy machine) to your proxy machine. This is done by combining IPTables (to select which traffic to divert) and Policy Routing (does the diverting).

I tested the following steps on OpenWrt Chaos Calmer (15.05.1, r48532) in VMware. They are based on [this guide](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/IptablesPolicyRoute).

First, to set up Policy Routing, you need iproute2. Install it:

```
opkg update # If you haven't done it since rebooting
opkg install ip
```

Then, open `/etc/firewall.user` with your favorite editor and insert the following commands:

```
PROXYIP4=192.168.1.10
PROXYIP6=fe80:dead:beef::10

CLIENTIFACE=br-lan

FWMARK=2

# Permit Squid box out to the Internet
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -s $PROXYIP4 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -s $PROXYIP6 -j ACCEPT

# Mark everything else on port 80 to be routed to the Squid box
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark $FWMARK
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark $FWMARK -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark $FWMARK
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark $FWMARK -j ACCEPT

# NP: Ensure that traffic from inside the network is allowed to loop back inside again.
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $CLIENTIFACE -o $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $CLIENTIFACE -o $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Fill 'proxy' routing table
ip route flush table proxy
ip route add default via $PROXYIP4 table proxy dev $CLIENTIFACE
ip -6 route add default via $PROXYIP6 table proxy dev $CLIENTIFACE
```

Make sure to adjust the variables as needed!

Then, edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, adding a line for the `proxy` table using any free ID:

```
...
201     proxy
```

The last piece is the policy for traffic marked with `$FWMARK`. Open `/etc/config/network` and create a rule entry:

```
config rule
    option mark 0x2
    option in lan
    option lookup proxy
```

Make sure the `in` network name is correct etc.

That concludes the OpenWrt part of the setup. The proxy machine has now (effectively) become the default gateway for HTTP traffic. If this machine runs Linux, you could continue with [this guide on TPROXY](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4).

The routing overhead should be minimal. The rest depends on the proxy host.

If you broke your Internet access, you can easily restore it by deleting the routing rule:

```
ip rule del fwmark 2
```

The rule can also be easily added again:

```
ip rule add fwmark 2 table proxy
```

## tl;dr

The proxy host must indeed be between the clients and the Internet. However, with clever routing, any directly reachable machine can be made the “Man in the Middle”.

Like so:

[image: traffic interception]

Comment: Thank you Daniel B! Do you know if I stand to gain any performance by bridging my modem to my router with the gateway proxy?

Comment: If all that's directly connected to your modem is the router, bridged mode is certainly the correct choice, if only to avoid double NAT. Be careful to not accidentally expose your network directly to the Internet while switching.

Comment: Here's the problem - I don't know how to set all of that up. I'm not asking you to tell me (though if you do I'll award the bonus on the spot!), but I need to be pointed in the right direction. Do I need to set up bridge mode on two of the ethernet connections of the gateway? Do I then need to do NAT and DHCP from the gateway instead of the router? Do I still need to route traffic to the gateway via IPtables? I'm lost when it comes to how that configuration should work.

Comment: I’m not sure we’re talking about the same thing. The “best” setup would be the modem in bridged mode, the router with DHCP WAN and NAT (OpenWrt’s default setup) and the rest as is. The proxy host remains a regular host (with a fixed IP address) in your local network. All you need to do is divert the traffic (my answer) and intercept it (linked guide). I’ve added an image to illustrate the traffic flow.

Comment: OK thanks, so there's no benefit to putting the proxy host physically between the router and the modem in your illustration, "bridging" those two devices together.

Comment: No benefit relevant for SOHO anyway. You’ll run into other limits before saturating links or the router’s CPU. It would just act as yet another router, which introduces additional configuration overhead and security implications (if improperly set up).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43760/discussion-between-adam-wykes-and-daniel-b).